# How to convert EEBCDIC file format to csv

Tags: ebcdic

I have a data file in .eic format and its hard to convert it to the readable format, any input will help. I have tried some of the online tools but in vain.

Edit - Have added Database Hierarchy if this helps to convert 1 .eic file to 9 files. The R-3 dataset is hierarchical in structure.  In an attempt to maintain the appropriate parent/child record relationship, the GR-ROOT-KEY field is pre-pended to all output child records.  The GR-CYCLE-KEY field is appended to all child records of the GR-CYCLE-RECORD parent record.

[Database Hirerachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh8p5.jpg)

Comment: do you mean `EBCDIC` ???. Is it `binary Ebcdic` or just `Text`. Is `Fixed-Length`, `VB` or are lines delimited with \n ???. Is there a Cobol Copybook for the file ???

Comment: What have you `tried` and what `happened` ???

Comment: What is .eic format ???

Comment: I don't have a Cobol copybook and tried some software online to convert it but no success. Here is the link to the file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dbpZSkJXU5UTdvWW16V2E4dW8

Yes I mean EBCDIC file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### File Definition

The files appears to be:

```
  Encoding: Binary Ebcdic (There are Packed-decimal ~ Cobol Comp-3 fields).
  Format: Fixed Length 
  Record Length: 422 bytes
  Multi-Record: Yes - I think there are 10 record types in the file
  Mainframe JCL Definition:  RECFM=FB,LRECL=422,...
```

#### File - Hex view

A hex view of the file (the first line is Text (ebcdic), the following 2 lines hold the hex value). It is basically a Mainframe ISPF Edit Style hex view.

[image]

#### Processing

To process, you really need the `Cobol Copybook` (or pl1 etc depending on the language used).

Your processing options are

- Process in Cobol / Whatever on the Mainframe / AS400 where ever it comes from.
- [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) (ideally with a Cobol Copybook)
- [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/), [CobolToXml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltoxml/)
  or some other program/project that can process Ebcdic Cobol. There are some Comercial packages that can.

The file is not suitable for conversion to Csv (unless you only want the header Records).
Conversion to Xml/Json would be possible.

#### File View

I have posted the RecordEditor-Xml description here:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/record-editor/discussion/467594/thread/d21a205c/

You would better off **getting a Cobol Copybook** and using that **instead !!!**

Looking at The file in the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) in full screen view:

[image: RecordEditor preferred view]

or Record View:

[image: Single Record View]

Answer (score 0):

### Using the RecordEditor - Layout Wizard

For this file It would be much better to import a **Cobol Copybook**.

In the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/), You can use the **Layout Wizard (**Record Layout >>> Layout Wizard** Menu option) yo define the file, it is tedious though.

- So Select **Record Layout >>> Layout Wizard** Menu option and enter cp037 (US - EBCDIC, there are a number EBCDIC variants e.g. cp273 is German Ebcdic)

[image]

- Hit the Right button at the bottom of the screen, you need to work out the **Record Length** in this case it is 422:

[image]

- Next enter the **Record Selection Field**, in this case it starts in column 1 and is 2 bytes long:

[image]

- Next enter the record Names (you can use **Right Click >>> Generate Names**)

[image]

- Next Select the fields, While the RecorEditor will select fields, you do need to check the fields and adjust if necessary. Clicking on the start of a field will create / delete the field. You will need to select the fields for every record type

[image]

- Then you need to enter field names (for every RecordType (you can use the **Right Click** menu to generate names).

[image]

---

While you can use the **Layout Wizard** to generate the `File Description`, it is tedious, It is much better to work from the Cobol Copybook.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I am not finding a Cobol Copybook for this but did found out 
DATABASE HIERARCHY

                        **********
                        * GRROOT *
                        * KEY=01 *
                        **********
                             *
                             ******************
                             *                *
                        **********       **********
                        *GRCYCLE *       *GRR3RMKS*
                        * KEY=02 *       * KEY=13 *
                        **********       ********

Comment: *
    *****************************************************************> A
    *           *           *           *           *            *
********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********
* GRR3I * * GRR3II * * GRR3V * * GRR3VI * *GRR3VII * * GRR3X *
* KEY=03 * * KEY=04 * * KEY=05 * * KEY=06 * * KEY=07 * * KEY=10 *
********** ********** ********** ********** ********** **********

A >**************
    *           *
********** **********
* GRR3XI * * GRR7   *
* KEY=11 * * KEY=12 *
********** **********
Do this help in getting 9 data files from a 1 .eic file?